# Why is it important to call publish() before replay()

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I've read many rx examples about publish() and replay(). In all tutorials, they say it's important to call publish() before calling replay(). Why is this so? What happens if you call replay() and never call publish()? It seems like the replay() operator would subscribe to the source observable and begin caching. Then anybody who comes along would get the same, complete data stream. The only reason I can see publish() changing the game is that it would delay subscription to the source observable until connect() is called. Is this right?

Comment: Can you post links to the "many rx examples"?

Comment: heres one but its also in the book im reading http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html

Comment: The statement "If you apply the Replay operator to an Observable before you convert it into a connectable Observable, the resulting connectable Observable will always emit the same complete sequence to any future observers, even those observers that subscribe after the connectable Observable has begun to emit items to other subscribed observers." is just plain confusing to me. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It's saying that everybody will always get the complete, full stream no matter when they subscribe. But I think we'd get that anyway, even if we don't call publish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You usually apply one or the other, but not both at the same time because `publish().replay()` has no practical difference to a plain `replay()` and `replay().publish()` is just a recipe for late consumers to not see the whole sequence.

> In all tutorials, they say it's important to call publish() before calling replay().

This is definitely wrong, where did you read it exactly?

> Is this right?

Both operators return a `ConnectableObservable` and you have to call `connect` in both cases to start the sequences. In both cases you should prepare consumers before calling connect or use `autoConnect(n)` to start the sequence after `n` consumers.

The difference between `publish` and `replay` that the latter caches some or all items and replays them to consumers no matter when they subscribe. The former doesn't retain any items, not even the latest like `BehaviorSubject`, and dispatches the item to consumers who are subscribed to it at that exact time.

Comment: I appreciate all your help thus far. I'm still stuck on the different between `replay()` and `replay().publish()`. What is the difference between the two recipes?

Comment: Replay will cache items and then `publish` will emit parts of it to its consumers as it consumes the cache, undoing the ability of the `replay()` to replay the same items to everybody regardless when they start to consume. There is no reasone I can think of for you to use `replay().publish()` together.

Comment: "There is no reasone I can think of for you to use replay().publish() together."

This is contradictory to the documentation which states

"You must Publish this connectable Observable before observers can subscribe to it, and then Connect to it in order to observe its emissions."

https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html

Comment: @mithunc there is no contradiction for two reasons: 1) the reactivex documentation was always wrong about "publish this connectable", 2) even if it was right by itself, it would still make no sense to publish a replay source.